Why doesn't the hide function pull through once playing the game?
I have created a maths game. I am trying to hide the difficulty levels when the user starts the game however after lots of attempts, I am having no luck. Please can someone help and explain where I am going wrong?
The questions are identified above this code, I have included it all in case I am missing something.
  // Function to start a quiz for a given level
  // Get HTML elements by their IDs
  function startQuiz(level) {
    const questions = quizData[level];
    const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
    const answerButtons = document.getElementById("answer-buttons");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-btn");

    // Variables to keep track of the current question index and the player's score
    let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    let score = 0;

    // Function to start the quiz by resetting variables and showing the first question
    function startQuizInternal() {
      currentQuestionIndex = 0;
      score = 0;
      updateUI();
    }

    // Function to update the UI with the current question and answer options
    function updateUI() {
      resetState();
      const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
      const questionNo = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
      questionElement.innerHTML = `${questionNo}. ${currentQuestion.question}`;

      // Create buttons for each answer option and attach event listeners
      currentQuestion.answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = answer.text;
        button.classList.add("btn");
        answerButtons.appendChild(button);
        if (answer.correct) {
          button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
        }
        button.addEventListener("click", handleAnswerSelection);
      });
    }

    // Function to reset the state of the quiz (clear answer buttons and hide next button)
    function resetState() {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      while (answerButtons.firstChild) {
        answerButtons.removeChild(answerButtons.firstChild);
      }
    }

    // Function to handle the selection of an answer
    function handleAnswerSelection(event) {
      const selectedBtn = event.target;
      const isCorrect = selectedBtn.dataset.correct === "true";
      if (isCorrect) {
        selectedBtn.classList.add("correct");
        score++;
      } else {
        selectedBtn.classList.add("incorrect");
      }
      disableAnswerButtons();
      nextButton.style.display = "block";
    }

    // Function to disable all answer buttons after an answer is selected
    function disableAnswerButtons() {
      Array.from(answerButtons.children).forEach(button => {
        if (button.dataset.correct === "true") {
          button.classList.add("correct");
        }
        button.disabled = true;
      });
    }

    // Function to handle the next button click
    function handleNextButtonClick() {
      currentQuestionIndex++;
      if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
        updateUI();
      } else {
        showScore();
      }
    }

    // Function to display the final score at the end of the quiz
    function showScore() {
      resetState();
      questionElement.innerHTML = `You scored ${score} out of ${questions.length}!`;
      nextButton.innerHTML = "Play Again?";
      nextButton.style.display = "block";
    }

    // Event listener for the next button
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
        handleNextButtonClick();
      } else {
        startQuizInternal();
      }
    });

    startQuizInternal();
  }

  function hideOtherLevels(selectedLevel) {
    const levels = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard'];
    levels.forEach(level => {
      if (level !== selectedLevel) {
        document.getElementById(level).style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        document.getElementById(level).style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
  }

  // Call appropriate level based on user selection or default
  function startGame(level) {
    if (level === 'easy' || level === 'medium' || level === 'hard') {
      startQuiz(level);
    } else {
      // Default to easy level if no level is specified
      startQuiz('easy');
    }
  }

  // Attach event listeners to start quiz buttons
  document.getElementById('easyButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    startGame('easy');
  });


  document.getElementById("mediumButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    startGame("medium");
  });

  document.getElementById("hardButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  startGame("hard");
  });
});


the only function not described is the one you're asking about! was that deliberate?

The code shown has no calls to hideOtherLevels at all. So it's not going to do anything.

I have included the function ```game-js
hideOtherLevels
does this need to be something else
